During migrating from infinispan v9.3 to v13, getting error in putAll cache update with Derby Database
During migrating from infinispan v9.3 to v13, getting error in putAll() cache update with Derby Database.
I am using derby 10.14 as my persistance store, when i am tyring to update a batch of data using putAll() method. It is failing with below error.
[blocking-thread-testnode-p3-t1] TRACE org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.sql.BaseTableOperations - Running batch upsert sql 'MERGE INTO "ISPN_STRING_TABLE_KEYCHAIN" USING (VALUES (?, ?, ?)) AS tmp (DATA_COLUMN, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN) ON (DATA_COLUMN = tmp.DATA_COLUMN) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TIMESTAMP_COLUMN = tmp.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN = tmp.ID_COLUMN WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DATA_COLUMN, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN) VALUES (tmp.DATA_COLUMN, tmp.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, tmp.ID_COLUMN)'
15722 [blocking-thread-testnode-p3-t1] TRACE org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.sql.BaseTableOperations - Running batch delete sql 'DELETE FROM "ISPN_STRING_TABLE_KEYCHAIN" WHERE ID_COLUMN = ?'
15732 [non-blocking-thread-testnode-p2-t14] ERROR org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor - ISPN000136: Error executing command PutMapCommand on Cache 'KEYCHAIN', writing keys [key40, key44, key43, key42, key41, key37, key36, key35...<92 other elements>]
org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: ISPN008037: Error while writing entries in batch to the database:
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.impl.BaseJdbcStore.lambda$batch$7(BaseJdbcStore.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The source table of a MERGE statement must be a base table or table function.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.sql.BaseTableOperations.batchUpdates(BaseTableOperations.java:179)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.common.impl.BaseJdbcStore.lambda$batch$7(BaseJdbcStore.java:196)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: ERROR 42XAL: The source table of a MERGE statement must be a base table or table function.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.MergeNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

I checked the query, it is using to update is coming from infinispan, below is the query for which it is complaining.
MERGE INTO "ISPN_STRING_TABLE_KEYCHAIN" USING (VALUES (?, ?, ?)) AS tmp (DATA_COLUMN, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN) ON (DATA_COLUMN = tmp.DATA_COLUMN) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TIMESTAMP_COLUMN = tmp.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN = tmp.ID_COLUMN WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (DATA_COLUMN, TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, ID_COLUMN) VALUES (tmp.DATA_COLUMN, tmp.TIMESTAMP_COLUMN, tmp.ID_COLUMN)'
Any configuration changes i am missing because the query is hardcoded in the infinispan 13 code base.
The same query get generated in infinispan9.3 but it doesn't complain in batch update there.
Thanks in Advance.
I am able to put single entry cache but batch update is complaining. The same query get generated in infinispan 9.3 but it doesn't complain there.
